# Type check ... rest fields of an object with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to write an interface or type with typescript to enforce the type of known fields, and also some dynamic ones.

Example:

```
const person = {
   children: [person1, person2],
   name: "X",
   dynamicField1: person3,
   dynamicField2: person4,
   dynamicField3: person5 
}

// Something that would look like this
interface Person {
  name: string;
  children: Person[];
  ...rest: Person;
}
```

Is it possible to to that in typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to to that in typescript ?

Yep, you can have your `Person` interface extend a record which allows any key/value like this:

```
interface Person extends Record<any, any> {
    name: string;
    children: Person[];
}
```